# Pygame bullet firerate not working sometimes

Tags: python, pygame, oop

i have made this bullet class but i have a problem with the firerate. Sometimes  i'm not able to shoot even when the little delay (700ms) between the two shots has ended. I guess it's due to the pygame.time.set_timer(). Anyways i'm looking for a quick solution because i wanna move on to work on another part of this game.

```
...

class Singlebullet(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.img = pygame.image.load(r'C:\Users\Salem\Documents\MyGame1\bullet.png')
        self.state = 'ready'
        self.speed = 0
        self.firerate = 700
    
    def shoot(self):
        if current_bullet_type == 'single':
            if self.state == 'ready':
                self.x = myplane.x + 71 
                self.y = myplane.y 
            if self.state == 'fire':
                self.speed = -13
            for event in events:
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN or event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                        self.state = 'fire'
                        pygame.time.set_timer(pygame.USEREVENT+1, self.firerate)
                if event.type == pygame.USEREVENT+1:
                    self.state = 'ready'
            MyScrollingScreen.blit(self.img, (self.x, self.y))
            self.y += self.speed
s1 = Singlebullet()
...
while running:
    ...
    s1.shoot()
    ...
```

Comment: Why do you shoot on space release too? Might want to make sure you're in "ready" state before shooting (starting the timer).

Comment: You seem to be misusing the set_timer function. Check the documentation to see how it should be used.

Comment: @Vaillancourt Thank you! I removed the _KEYUP_ event and added the condition that the bullet should be in **ready state** before starting the timer and everything worked ! btw , i see that the documentation doesn't provide enough information about everything and that's why i missuse some functions.

Comment: Glad your issue is fixed! You can write (and accept) an answer explaining how you fixed it!

Comment: Done, but i can't accept it until tomorrow

Comment: All right, no worries :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, i realized that i was missusing the `pygame.time.set_timer()` function. In fact, this resulted in making me able to shoot the bullet only when the timer resets itself, but i wasn't able to shoot when the countdown timer starts again.
Then i added the condition that the bullet should be in ready state before starting/restarting the timer (now, the timer won't be restarted unless the bullet's state is set to 'ready' and i click the space button):

```
for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE and self.state == 'ready':
                    self.state = 'fire'
                    pygame.time.set_timer(pygame.USEREVENT+1, self.firerate)
            if event.type == pygame.USEREVENT+1:
                self.state = 'ready'
```

And i have also removed the `if event.type == pygame.KEYUP` as it was absolutely useless.